# Discriminate only one case of union in Typescript

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is there a way to discriminate options of a union one by one, and if no case matches a discriminated interface it will fallback to another interface ?

```ts
enum ActionType {
    create = 'create',
    delete = 'delete',
    update = 'update',
}

interface ActionHistoryDefault {
    type: ActionType;
    entityId: number | string | undefined // common interface, all available types here
    entityType: string;
}

interface ActionHistoryInsert {
    type: ActionType.create
    entityId: undefined;
}

type ActionHistoryOptions = ActionHistoryDefault | ActionHistoryInsert

declare const a: ActionHistoryOptions

if (a.type === ActionType.create) {
    a.entityId // should be undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional generic types to discriminate them instead

```
enum ActionType {
    create = 'create',
    delete = 'delete',
    update = 'update',
}

interface ActionHistoryDefault {
    type: ActionType;
    entityId: number | string | undefined 
    entityType: string;
}

interface ActionHistoryInsert extends ActionHistoryDefault {
    type: ActionType.create
    entityId: undefined;
}

type ActionHistoryOptions<T extends ActionType = any> = T extends ActionType.create ? ActionHistoryInsert : ActionHistoryDefault

declare const a: ActionHistoryOptions<ActionType.create>
a.entityId // undefined

declare const b: ActionHistoryOptions
b.entityId // number | string | undefined
```

If you pass nothing to generic types of `ActionHistoryOptions`, it will be `ActionHistoryDefault` by default.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYUDeAsAFBRlRwBOwAhgngLxQDkVt9zANCeVACbAANsHpQmzAcI7dS5MNj51GLeYukkAviRJIQ9SgDMacPPGRoAEkgDOCFJUwARYEbCCEBHuQQ5gALlhEVAxfAG4vMlBkHwBJPgDwCAAjYEooAB8oW0pdAHMMqDAQAQNdYD4oCKgopB8sXADsvPDiLWIdPVSjE0DzECtbe0wYkGtUj2AAD3pi617ggbsHZ1d3T1kyHwb5tHrgADo2JSqa2PjC4pcyvha2ki3TIMsbJcwAeWw+6wAedGrp0B8OZmYJ7MRQGggTAAPnBfymMyBOxCuEO1CUUAA-MjFkMRmNKB4AiDnoNli4aG4ENpiAI4IIaNQKGhbBDiU9+i8hh8vjoDAAKGj7B5iBhMEkog5HegASnWvCFp2GFQA9CqLiVrpoaSQ6QymXAWR4kuy+riHDzgtYSEl9kq4lA1VBEik0pkmiB8pkipqQOUoEA)

---

Thanks for [@PiotrSzyma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6082882/piotr-szyma) suggestion in the comment section.

Instead of using a common type, you can have separate types with different actions. Your type checks will be applied properly under if-statements

```
enum ActionType {
    create = 'create',
    delete = 'delete',
    update = 'update',
}

interface ActionHistoryDelete {
    type: ActionType.delete;
    entityId: number | string | undefined
    entityType: string;
}

interface ActionHistoryUpdate {
    type: ActionType.update;
    entityId: string;
}

interface ActionHistoryInsert {
    type: ActionType.create
    entityId: undefined;
}

type ActionHistory = ActionHistoryInsert | ActionHistoryUpdate | ActionHistoryDelete;

declare const a: ActionHistory

if (a.type === ActionType.create) {
    a.entityId // undefined
}

if (a.type === ActionType.update) {
    a.entityId // should be string
}

if (a.type === ActionType.delete) {
    a.entityId // number | string | undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYUDeAsAFBRlRwBOwAhgngLxQDkVt9zANCeVACbAANsHpQmzAcI7dS5MNj51GLeYukkAviRJIQ9SgDMacPPGRoAEkgDOCFJUwARISLxFZZBDmAAuWIlQMbwA6SVcAbh5yUGQvAEk%20P3AIACNgSigAHyhbSl0AcyyoMBABA11gPiiyGKQvLFw-XILI4i1iHT10oxN-cxArW3tMAFUFJQJqqC9GvsCG4GDVJVbeWvjEnIQ8kHzW9s79HtMAyxs7BziQa3SESY9p7z8zeZC2JSn1zAS-ErKKvj7bTEGYnfqDC6YMRzM5DS7XW5FF6wyFjNR4bLIgbnYbOKTAVokARwQQ0agUNC2KA0Z6nbFwzDApAGKAAChowVBYgYTCxC2C73oAEp7rwOV8ElAAPRS4qlYDlECVTRMlnsznebm8un85bC0XkcV6OrfPjS2XWAAWKDAgjNaTl-yVVTaqrZHK5PO1-X5YX17jFwQlZplUGSaQy2WauyKfwVAJVxCAA)

Comment: Thanks ! I know the question is specific to one case, do you have by any chance an example that works for 2 cases out of 4 ? I'd like to see if that can potentially evolve in an easy way

Comment: WDYT about this approach? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYUDeAsAFBRlRwBOwAhgngLxQDkVt9zANCeVACbAANsHpQmzAcI7dS5MNj51GLeYukkAviRJIQ9SgDMacPPGRoAEkgDOCFJUwARYEbCCEBHuQQ5gALlhEVAxfADpJETwAH0DzENxQ1SUAbi8yUGQfAEk+APAIACNgSigY20pdAHNSqDAQAQNdYD4oAHpWihQICDQoXX0jE04oGkFBEYA3GiRBGgLhKB9caygAC2LgNKgMpB8sXADyqtTiLWIdPWLB0yDLGzsHLJBrYo8iWTIl-1jg-eBQthKLY7bK5Wr1FxNPgnM4kL4-O62eyYMQIkBWJGPZ6vGpmYIYh5OFw0NwIE4kARwWbUTrPDw0AJ4xGE7TEJAGKAAChooXhDH5aL+AOoSgAlJ4PiNQiDMDk2h1rKsUG4WkVwQ0oZogA

Comment: This approach looks good ! Could you suggest the edit so I can approve the answer ?

Comment: @nook I found out Piotr Szyma's solution is genuinely good. You can get rid of a common type and have separate types for each action. All type checks will work properly!

Comment: I'd still stick with the `type` property being an union of 2 values of the enum, instead of having one different all the time, which will result in a regular discriminated union. The objective here was the avoid repetition if both enums share the same types. But the answer is very good.